# Google Apps Script - Calling a function involving moving files across Google Share Drive folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not familiar with Google Apps Script and I'm having trouble figuring out how to call a function.

The below function is intended to move a file from the Google Shared Drive folder its current in to a new folder with the Google Shared Drive.

```
function moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives({parentFolderId, destinationFolderId, fileId }) { 
  const data = Drive.Files.update({}, fileId, null, {
    addParents: destinationFolderId, 
    removeParents: parentFolderId, 
    supportsAllDrives: true, 
    fields: 'title, embedLink',
 });
 console.log('File Moved', data.title, data.embedLink);
}
```

I tried to call this function in a macro style with the below code but that didn't work. In the google apps script page, a syntax error would show up saying: "Syntax error: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token line: 11 file: Code.gs":

```
moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives(1FaTWCQc-asflsdfsfAngr, 1setTISPSknysd-sl3UepcFnptDCA, 1R9gLCWpsfasafsdf-9QZwef44HKLCI)
```

What am I doing wrong? I had selected the function and inputted the Shared Drive Folder Ids for the original folder, destination folder, and the file ID. I've also enabled the Drive API, so I'm unsure how to properly call the function.

Comment: Could you point out which line is line 11? And is `1FaTWCQc-asflsdfsfAngr` the parent folder ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With minor modifications to the code provided, I was able to make it work on my end:

### Changes:

```
//I've removed the curly brackets from this function signature. 
function moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives(parentFolderId, destinationFolderId, fileId) { 
...
```

```
//To call the function, the parameters must be in String format (within quotes). 
moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives("<PARENT_FOLDER_ID>", "<DESTINATION_FOLDER_ID>", "<FILE_ID>")
```

- Additionally, make sure the caller/actor of the function have `Contributor`, `Content manager`, or `Manager` roles over both parent Shared Drive and Destination.
- If `fileId` is a folder, make sure the caller is a Workspace Drive Administrator.
- For more inforamtion regarding requisites to moving files to Shared Drives, please refer to [this Help Center article](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310460)

Comment: Thanks @Gustavo! This was helpful and I was able to call the function. One remaining issue though, there's a message that pops up in red after even though I was able to successfully move files across folders. Here's the message: "HttpResponseException: Response Code: 404. Message: Not Found." Do you know why this message pops up in red after?

Comment: Just with this error message it is hard to say. Depending where it was triggered, it has different meanings. For example, if it was returned from the act of fetching a Drive file, it might mean that the caller does not have access to that file or that ID doesn't exist. 

Can you share the full error text and which line it was triggered (on your script)? I'm interested in co-relating which line this exception was triggered and which method was being executed at the time of triggering.

Comment: @JacksonSmith In any case, you should be able to pinpoint where the http error effectively occurred and interpret the scenario based on what method was being called. Since this is a response from the API endpoint, most likely this is not a coding issue but a matter of fixing the information sent in conformity of each API method set of rules. If this information helped you, please remember to accept it. Cheers!